# Serial device ttyUSB permissions brokes after replug device

Tags: usb, tty, udev

I have a 3D-printer, that connected to my laptop (under fresh installation of Ubuntu 19.04) by USB-cable.

As far as understand, 3D-printer creates virtual COM-port through USB. Right after OS is loaded, I can connect to my printer without any problems. But if I unplug the USB-cable and plug it again, connection could not be established.

**That I tried already:**

1. User added to `tty` and `dialout` groups
2. Add udev-rule (created file /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules with content: `KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",MODE="0666"`)
3. modemmanager removed

Right after OS is loaded, I typed command

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And got expectable output:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 сен  9 18:37 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And after replugging USB-cable same command output is:

```
crw------- 1 root root 188, 0 сен  9 18:56 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So, my question is: WHY?! And, how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Output for command `groups` is:

```
igor adm tty dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

**EDIT2**

I unplug the cable, then plug it again. And got incorrect permissions on `/dev/ttyUSB0` again. **Then I leave the computer for few hours to work...** And after that, permissions magically turns into:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 сен 13 13:47 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So, right permission applied to `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but it takes too much time...

**EDIT3**

Output for command `tail -f dmesg $(find . -name \*log)` in directory /var/log:

```
==> ./kern.log <==
Sep 13 22:38:45 igor kernel: [129395.359713] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468908] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.63
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468912] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468914] usb 2-1.1: Product: USB2.0-Serial
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.469312] ch341 2-1.1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.470094] usb 2-1.1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

==> ./syslog <==
Sep 13 22:38:45 igor kernel: [129395.359713] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468908] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.63
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468912] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.468914] usb 2-1.1: Product: USB2.0-Serial
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.469312] ch341 2-1.1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
Sep 13 22:38:46 igor kernel: [129395.470094] usb 2-1.1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Sep 13 22:39:47 igor systemd-udevd[428]: message repeated 4139 times: [ Process 'hid2hci --method=dell --devpath=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.2/2-1.6.2:1.0' failed with exit code 1.]
```

So, I see an error message, but can not understand, what's wrong.

Comment: Are you a member of `dialout` group? Pplease add output of `groups` command to the question. Why you have created personal udev-rule?

Comment: Yes, user is memeber of `dialout` group. And it is not worked. So, then I tried to custom udev-rule... without success too.

Comment: In a terminal window: `cd /var/log ; tail -f dmesg $(find . -name \*log)`  Then unplug and plug in your cable again and *maybe* you'll find something.

Comment: @ИгорьЧайкин Try debugging using `udevadm trigger ...` . Also try raising the rule order like `90-myusb.rules` may be there was a racing condition.